# Intento cambiar el valor de una variable en Django con DetailView

Tags: django

estoy creando una aplicación que tiene una especie de bandeja de entrada para mensajes entre usuarios.

El modelo Mensaje tiene un campo booleano llamado "leido", que hará q en el template se muestre en mensajes leidos o no leidos.

Bien, mi idea es acceder a un mensaje a través de una VBC tipo DetailView
me gustaría hacer que al abrir esa vista el campo leido fuese = True.

el probado lo siguiente y me cambia el valor del campo, pero es como si me eliminase cosas momentaneamente puesto que no me deja acceder a la vista del mensaje

```
class MensajeDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Mensaje
 
     def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(MensajeDetailView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        obj.leido = True
        obj.save()
```

en el template tengo esta condición, y me entra directamente al else si uso esa función

```
<article>
       {% if object.idEmisor == request.user or object.idReceptor == request.user %}
      <div style="margin-left: 3%;">
          <h3>De: {{object.idEmisor}}</h3>
          <h3>Para: {{object.idReceptor}}</h3>

          
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left: 3%;">
           <h3>Asunto: {{object.asunto}}</h3>
           <p>{{object.texto}}</p>
      </div>
      {% else %} 
      <p>No puedes leer este mensaje por no ser el emisor ni el receptor</p>
      {% endif %} 
   </article>
```

he probado tambien lo siguiente

```
class MensajeDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Mensaje

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super (MensajeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['leido'] = True
        
        return context
```

Pero no consigo que se almacene el cambio a True, ya que no se como hacer un .save(), context.save() no funciona, ya que es context es un diccionario. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el objeto de esta manera:

```
class MensajeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Mensaje

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super (MensajeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.leido = True
        obj.save()
        
        return context
```